# How do I update the path of a venv in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I moved a project from one directory into another, and now my venv won't work.  Is there a way to update where PyCharm looks for the venv?  I tried the 'Add existing local interpreter' dialog and it didn't work (after clicking "Ok" the interpreter I selected doesn't show up in the list of available interpreters):

[image]

Comment: Venv can't be easily moved, it's not about pycharm configuration. Delete your venv and recreate it.

Comment: @STerliakov Yes it does, thank you.  If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.